# cscope searching for local functions C++

Tags: c++, emacs, cscope

Im new to cscope and im trying to search for a local function when im in a class and also in a header file. 
When im in the header file i want to search for a function that is in the current file, but instead it searches the whole source tree for the function leaving me with a list of functions in many files and then i have to scroll through all the results to find local one. There must be an easier way to do this??
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Do following:

1. Copy and save the function name somewhere
2. Copy the header file name wherein you want to search the function
   and search that header file (there is a tab for searching files)
3. Once you are inside that file, search the function which you copied
   earlier using local search of the editor you are using (say grepping
   pattern using `/` for `vi` or `less`)